# Confusion about subjectivity

Tags: subjectivity, criticism

I am having some confusions about subjectivism. I am a pretty new to this subject. Here is my question:
Subjectivists believe that everything is subjective, including philosophy and morals. So, how does criticizing, or calling some philosophy 'bad' make sense? (in the perspective of a subjectivist).

Comment: Mathematics and logic are also part of metaphysics, like morals or aesthetics, and can be _bad_ as well. Any dialog implies common agreements about subjectivities: some say that _objectivism is just a shared subjectivism_. So, 1=2 is a "bad mathematical operation" because you and me have common agreements about mathematical objects: we share the same subjective mathematical notions. In the same line, saying that "fascism is good" is probably a bad philosophy for most, or "being egoist" is a "bad" moral rule for most.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is absolute moral relativism impossible?](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/questions/78872/is-absolute-moral-relativism-impossible)

Comment: Indeed strictly speaking the often heard speech of calling someone not making sense doesn't make sense on its own as any epistemology as a web of all kinds of *beliefs* unavoidably contains its own subjective element in the Cartesian dualist's terms which is usually defined in the first chapter or introduction section of modern western philosophy. But later you'll learn other different ideologies and a branch called moral philosophy (ethics), so you'll have more perspectives for what *ought* to be the norm or the "right" way of thinking per social convention or specific expert domain...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It's easy to oversimplify the concept of subjectivism. For instance — on the most superficial level — 'subjectivism' might refer to (using non-standard terminology):

- **Solipsism**: The belief that one's subjective experience is the only truth, and that all other people are manifestations of one's own subjective experience, without subjective experiences of their own. This is one way of interpreting Descartes' '*cogito ergo sum*'.
- **Intersubjectivity (linguistic/symbolic)**: The belief that reality is a composite of the subjective experiences of a community of people, carried primarily in language and symbolic interaction. Thus something like a traffic law has no ontological existence — it only exists within the minds of people — but still has significant 'real' effects in the world.
- **Intersubjectivity (scientific/ontic)**: The belief that reality is a composite of the collective subjective experience of some underlying objective/ontological world. E.g. scientific inference, where subjective experience is collated, abstracted, and formalized into a subjective concept that seems to have objective reach.

Any form of intersubjectivity carries the suggestion that collective knowledge *can be* (not necessarily *is*) superior to individual knowledge on purely pragmatic grounds. Collective knowledge integrates greater quantities of subjective experience, opening the possibility that individual misperceptions and biases can be balanced out by a weight of external experience. Thus as individuals assimilate broader sources of collective knowledge, their own (individual) subjectivity becomes more sophisticated, nuanced, and developed: aka 'better'. Some people assume that there is a 'best' that this bettering aims for; others assume an unfixed, process-oriented system of communal adaptation. The jury is still out on that one...

Comment: Isn't "cogito ergo sum" from Descartes?

Comment: @Barmar: Yeaaaaah. Total brain fart.

Comment: I might not have noticed except that it was the answer to a Jeopardy question a day or 2 ago.

Answer (score 3):

From E.E. Sleinis' [Nietzsche's Revaluation of Values: A Study in Strategies](https://books.google.gg/books?id=AlCxstLOlDwC&pg=PA59&source=gbs_toc_r&cad=4#v=onepage&q&f=false), page 59

> [Nietzsche's] position is not that any view is as good as any other
> view either in regard to value judgements or to judgements about the
> world.  In considering values, we cannot do better than perspectival
> *truth*, but we can certainly do worse. There are still better perspectives and worse perspectives, and these need to be sorted by
> subjecting them to rational scrutiny. Provided only that one desires
> to maximise value, the ground is set for an inquiry into how such
> desire can be met.

Comment: Very nice (+1) but I wonder about this formulation: is perspective truth? Whose perspective is truth? The truth is "in" perspectivalism, certainly according to N it would seem -- but "the truth" reflects back our own desire for it, our own way of understanding it. The Truth doesn't belong to either relative forms or absolute principles etc, and Nietzsche would emphasize it is a useful fiction etc

Comment: In this perspective truth is what you think is true.  In a more forceful form it is justice, as quoted [here](https://philosophy.stackexchange.com/a/84530/5154).